# My Theme - Cart Page Design Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9

My theme frontend design working fine in all other pages except cart and checkout page.. I don't know whatz the problem.

Comment: Check if you have enabled persistent. Then check in persistent folder.

Comment: Do you have a custom module for the checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you faced a conflict. The conflict is with displaying the module’s output in the .phtml template files.

Likely you have any custom module which is displayed on checkout or you have custom checkout itself. And this module or modules have own custom blocks with custom templates. Or this module / these modules have changed layout structure.

The information you have given is not enough to answer.

But you could try to identify the problem using the magento red blocks.

1. Log in to your Magento admin backend
2. Go to System->Configuration
3. Scroll to the bottom and click Advanced->Developer
4. In the dropdown menu on the top-left, select the store view that is loading on your homepage
5. Expand the "Debug" section, uncheck "Use Website", and set "Profiler", "Template Path Hints", and "Add Block Names to Hints" to Yes